How to upload to NAS via java springboot application
So im working on file upload feature which uploads a png file to a Net app NAS and Accessing this NAS share on a VM requires that i add an export, this will grant the VM permission to mount the storage.
After completeing the steps and adding a mount point when i try to upload a file using the below code
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream;

@RestController
public class FileUploadController {
 
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String nasUrl = "smb://your-nas-address/path/to/directory/";
        String username = "your-username";
        String password = "your-password";
 
        try {
            String destinationUrl = nasUrl + file.getOriginalFilename();
            SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(destinationUrl, new jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, username, password));
            SmbFileOutputStream smbFileOutputStream = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
            smbFileOutputStream.write(file.getBytes());
            smbFileOutputStream.close();
            return "File uploaded successfully!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "File upload failed: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}

i get this erorr
Error at index 0 in: "C2C_lkasdlajsdlkasjd6676q3e2qubd"

Since I'm a beginner any guidance on this will be helpful
